# Chabad adding word KODESH to Shabbat Candle blessing

Tags: chabad, candle-lighting

Chabad adds the word "kodesh" to the Shabbat candle blessing.  In Shulchan Aruch HaRav RSZ has the standard, regular blessing, but the Siddur is later, so they follow that.  But, my REAL question is:  how can (even a Rebbe) change the blessing that has been around since Geonic times? Isn't that "beyond the pale" of even his authority?  Does adding an extra word render it a Bracha Le-vatala, or at least equivalent to not even saying the blessing?

Comment: וכל המשנה ממטבע שטבעו חכמים בברכות, אינו אלא טועה.  ואם שינה את המטבע, הואיל והזכיר אזכרה ומלכות ועניין הברכה, ואפילו בלשון חול, יצא. http://mechon-mamre.org/i/2501.htm

Comment: See discussion of this question, in Shut Divrei Yisrael ([3:136:1](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22652&st=&pgnum=137)), by Rabbi Yisrael Weltz.

Comment: @Double AA could we have a translation please. There maybe some who are not fluent in Hebrew. Many thanks.

Comment: A little searching around yields that the addition קודש goes at least as far back as תקוני שבת ע"פ האריז"ל, first printed in 1596. Whether the addition of the word comes from the Arizal too, I don't know, but at any rate it has a pedigree a lot older than Chabad.